# Quando e onde instanciar uma classe?

Tags: php, classes

Ao realizar o projeto, é recomendável instanciar uma Classe no próprio arquivo onde está implementada

> (Ex.: "nome_da_classe.Class.php"),

fazendo com que ela seja instanciada mesmo sem ser usada no sistema em diversos momentos

OU

somente quando precisam acessar algum método dela?

Comment: Só crie um objeto quando for usar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve instanciar um objeto apenas quando for utilizar, por exemplo: Uma classe Carro onde você precise armazenar a placa e usar algum método da mesma.

### Carregamento de classes

Porém no seu exemplo você deu a ideia de estar importando uma classe pro seu arquivo PHP e realmente isso é um problema já que você vai estar carregando itens que naquele momento não vai usar, além de ter que ficar enchendo seu código de include.

Para esse segundo caso, o PHP tem o *spl_autoload_register*, uma Autoloading que já fazem todo esse serviço para você. Vou deixar o link da documentação do AutoLoading abaixo para você poder se aprofundar mais sobre.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php